# Contains word Facebook group API SDK PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

Here is the sample code I have used when I get the script to display all the groups I am a member of facebook. How can I make it so it only shows the groups that contain the word "blog"?

```
$fql_query = 'select gid, name from group where gid IN (SELECT gid FROM group_member WHERE uid='.$fbuser.')';
$postResults = $facebook->api(array( 'method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => $fql_query ));

foreach ($postResults as $postResult) {
   echo '<br><option value="'.$postResult["gid"].'">'.$postResult["name"].'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no LIKE operator in fql, but you can use **IN** operator as-

```
select gid, name from group 
where gid IN 
  (SELECT gid FROM group_member WHERE uid='.$fbuser.') 
  AND strpos(lower(name), lower("Test")) >= 0
```

Comment: name is not a member of the group_member table.

Comment: If you see carefully, I've used name for the `group` table not the `group_member`. Give it a try

Comment: and if i use:  $fql_query = 'select gid, name from group where gid IN (SELECT gid FROM group_member WHERE uid='.$fbuser.' AND strpos(name, "blog") >= 0)'; i get Parser error: unexpected '(' at position 0.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sahil Mittal, but nothing difference :P

Comment: Haha, you missed the bracket after `$fbuser`, dont afraid just copy paste my code :P

Comment: now it worked. How can i do so it could contain the word blog. but the word "blogsuper", or whatever. if it finds the letters blog? whatever if its in a word or not?

Comment: Didnt got you, can you elaborate with example. And you didnt marked the ans as correct :-/

Comment: sure.

if the name of the group is: "blog europe" it will get the word. 
but if its named "blogword" it wont show. how can it read the word from a word? if it have the name blog in it, no matter if its in its own word or not, it will show/ be used?

Comment: of course it will show, you must have added a `space` after `blog` that's why ayou are not getting `blogword` in the result

Comment: strpos(name, "blog") >= 0';

no space there.

Comment: atm it uses: 

$fql_query = 'select gid, name from group where gid IN (SELECT gid FROM group_member WHERE uid='.$fbuser.') AND strpos(name, "blog") >= 0';

Comment: found out that its searching after "blog" and not "Blog". how can i do so it search both? no matter if its capitalized or not.

Comment: Just use the `lower`, ive edited the answer pl check

Comment: since im missing the results of a few. since "blogNorge" and "blog norway" should be in the list aswell.

Comment: they will come of course. If now its not coming then it must nit be coming even in the complete result

Comment: and still if you find any awkward result, post as a new question.